# How to combine two objects in mongodb aggregation project stage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I had the following array of structure in my aggregation pipeline. Tried merge objects and setUnion operators.

```
{ 
  combs:[
    [
      {
        name:"A",
        c_type:"A"
      },
      {
        type:"visual",
        severity:"Normal"
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        name:"B",
        c_type:"B"
      },
      {
        type:"visual",
        severity:"Normal"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

I am expecting the following results to produce some statistics. Please help me.

```
{ 
  combs:[
    {
      name:"A",
      c_type:"A",
      type:"visual",
      severity:"Normal"
    }
    {
      name:"B",
      c_type:"B",
      type:"visual",
      severity:"Normal"
     }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to achieve without $unwind operation?"*

Well YES. As long as your structure of *arrays of arrays* is consistently mapped that way  then you really only need a single stage in the pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
     "combs": {
       "$map": {
         "input": "$combs",
         "in": { "$mergeObjects": "$$this" }
       }
     }
  }}
])
```

So really the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator takes place here as a much more efficient method than [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) for processing each array element. Also since [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) is expecting *"an array of objects"*, this is what each element of your *array of arrays* actually is. So simply `{ "$mergeObjects": "$$this" }` on each *outer* member of the array.

Produces the output from your supplied data:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d8865c273375a6a4cc9e76a"),
        "combs" : [
                {
                        "name" : "A",
                        "c_type" : "A",
                        "type" : "visual",
                        "severity" : "Normal"
                },
                {
                        "name" : "B",
                        "c_type" : "B",
                        "type" : "visual",
                        "severity" : "Normal"
                }
        ]
}
```

Generally you should always prefer an inline processor like [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) or other array operators in preference to [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) where applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this aggregation query

```
db.collection.aggregate([
     { $unwind: "$combs" },
     { $addFields: { combs: { $mergeObjects: "$combs" }}},
     { $group: { _id: "$_id", combs: { $push: "$combs" }} }
 ])
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve without $unwind operation? @Ashok